# Is Raspberry Pi 2 the right choice for me?

Tags: video

I am a complete noob, with zero programming or coding. I'm looking to set up an exhibition of optical illusions, so i need approximately 20 animations running constantly on mounted PC screens. My questions:

1. Is a Raspberry Pi powering each screen the best/most affordable/reliable method of achieving this? If not, what would you do?
2. What slideshow/presentation app would work best, if I go with Raspberry Pi?
3. My plan is to set the Pi's up to start running the animation when I hit the main switch in the morning, and stop at night. Would it be better just to have them never stop running, and just power down the screens?

Thanks in advance, Paddy.

Comment: [This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=127279) guy asked something similar that might help. Looks like you might have some stuttering problem at higher resolutions. It also depends on the codec of your animations.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using Raspberry Pis to power the screens is probably a relatively affordable solution, and reasonably reliable. If it's the *best* solution, I dare not say.
2. If you are using animations, you should probably save them as movies and play them with `mplayer`, `VLC` or `omxplayer`.
3. It is definitely possible to make them play content automatically on startup, but it will require some tinkering. Probably then easier to just let them run.